# Getting error when building android app with release build variant that does not appear in debug or beta

Tags: android, kotlin

If I try to build my android app with beta (production like) or debug build variant I don't get any error, but if I try to use release variant, I get the following error:

```
kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KotlinReflectionInternalError: Could not compute caller for function: public constructor MyClass(from: java.time.LocalDate?, to: java.time...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is because of Proguard being enabled on release variant.

Try adding the following Proguard rule in `proguard-rules.pro`

```
-keepnames MyClass (replace with fully qualified class)
```

The code above will shrink the class but not obfuscate it.